# What does the weights of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ look like as a Lie-module?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a finite dimensional semisimple Lie algebra with Cartan subalgebra $H$, $\Phi$ the roots of $L$, $\Lambda_r = \mathbb{Z}\Phi$ the root lattice, $\Lambda_w$ the weight lattice and $\Lambda(V) = \mathbb{Z}\{\text{weights of $V$}\}$ the subgroup of $\Lambda_w$ generated by all the weights.

Let $V$ be a Lie-module with corresponding representation $\rho :L \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V)$, and suppose it is faithful. I want to show that $\Lambda_r \subseteq \Lambda(V)$.

I equipped $L$ with the adjoint representation and $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ with the $L$-action $X.- = [\rho(X),-]$ thus making $\rho$ a Lie-module homomorphism.

Let $\alpha \in \Phi$, $h\in H$, then $L_\alpha \neq 0$ so there exists some $x\in L$ such that $[hx]=\alpha(h)x = h.x$, therefore roots of $L$ are weights of $L$ with the adjoint representation.

Furthermore, $\rho(x)\neq 0$ due to $\rho$ being faithful, so $$h.\rho(x) = [\rho(h),\rho(x)] = \rho([hx]) = \rho(\alpha(h)x) = \alpha(h)\rho(x)$$
So $\alpha$ is also a weight of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ with the $L$-action defined above.

Now it remains to show that $\alpha$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of weights of $V$.  We know that $\mathfrak{gl}(V) \cong V^*\otimes V$, so let $(f\otimes v) \in V^* \otimes V$, $w\in V$, $h\in H$ and suppose $\lambda$ is the weight of $(f\otimes v)$

After some compution (which might be wrong, but I have a broken thumb so I won't type it all) I got

$$(h.(f\otimes v))(w) = f(w)\rho(h)v-f(\rho(h)w)v = \lambda(h)f(w)(v)$$

and I can't see how to proceed, or even if this is a good approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I would like to show that if $\Lambda'$ is another subgroup of $\Lambda_w$ containing $\Lambda_r$, then $\Lambda' = \Lambda(V)$. Could you drop a hint on showing that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here is an idea that I think should work, but there is an important detail missing: Let $\alpha$ and $x$ be as you have them (so $[hx] = \alpha(h)x$ for all $h$ in the Cartan). Now pick an element $v\in V_0$ (i.e. in the $0$-weightspace), such that $x.v\neq 0$. Then $x.v$ will have weight $\alpha$ in $V$. So the missing detail is to show that there is some element in the $0$-weightspace which is not annihilated by this given $x$, and this should follow from the rep being faithful.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Great! That is so much simpler than what I attempted. Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to show the missing detail?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Well, since $x\in L_\alpha \neq 0$ then $x.v=\rho(x)v \neq 0$ for $x\neq 0$ since it's faithful. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Yes, that argument is not quite complete (you have $\rho(x)\neq 0$, but that does not necessarily mean that $\rho(x)v\neq 0$). I think the argument should still be doable, but I could not quite get that detail worked out.

Comment: In the problem, a faithful L-module is defined via the fact that $x.(-) \neq 0$ on $V$ for all $x \neq 0$ in $L$. And since $x.(-) = \rho(x)(-)$ it seems to work out?

Comment: Right, but that does not mean that $x.v\neq 0$ for all $v\neq 0$, it just means that for each $x$ there is at least one $v$ with $x.v \neq 0$ (but for the argument I have in mind, we need to show that there is in fact such a $v$ in $V_0$, which is obviously a priori stronger).

Comment: Oh of course. Hm, I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the help!